# JFXButton looks clicked right after start

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, desktop, scenebuilder

One of my menu buttons(left) looks already clicked or highlighted right after start.[image]

I don't have any actions attached to these buttons yet so when i click this button everything starts looking like it should

All three buttons look the same:

```
  <JFXButton layoutX="14.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="101.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f72241; -fx-background-radius: 100;" text="M/M(a,b)/1" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
        <Font size="15.0" />
     </font>
  </JFXButton>
  <JFXButton layoutX="150.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="101.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f72241; -fx-background-radius: 100;" text="M/M(a,b)/c" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
        <Font size="15.0" />
     </font>
  </JFXButton>
  <JFXButton layoutX="285.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="101.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f72241; -fx-background-radius: 100;" text="M/GI(1,s)/1" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
        <Font size="15.0" />
     </font>
  </JFXButton>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the focus!

There are 2 solutions to this:

Giving focus for something else on shown.

```
button.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
    if(nv != null)
        nv.requestFocus();
});
```

Or setting focus traversable to false

```
button.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

You can set focus traversable in fxml too.

Comment: in that case i have to give my button an id and do `.setFocusTraversable(false)` in my java code. thats not gonna look that good cause i config my view through scene builder. update:

Comment: You can set focus traversable in scene builder too.